# How to use a lookup table to populate a combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to populate a combobox with values from a named tabel. I've been struggling and managed to come up with the following code:

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Range("SourceTable")
SourceBox.List = Arr
```

This populates the combobox with the values from the 1st column of the table SourceTable, which exists of 2 columns. I've got the following question:

- Is there something comparable as in HTML (I come from a webdev background) that you can set the name of an element and store a separate value as well?
- Is there a way to store the second column instead of the first like in above code?
- How would you refactor this code, because it seems like a detour of populating a single ComboBox

Thanks

Comment: maybe something like Range("SourceTable").Columns(2).Range?

Answer (score 2):

The ActiveX combobox object you are using supports multiple columns. It defaults to one. The columns can have their widths set as well. So what you want to do is set it to use two columns, and then set their widths to hide the first column and show the second. Something like:

```
Sub loadcombo()
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Arr = Range("SourceTable")
    SourceBox.ColumnCount = 2
    SourceBox.ColumnWidths = "0;1"
    SourceBox.List = Arr
End Sub
```

Then you can use the comboBox's `value` property to get that first hidden column and it's `text` property to get the second column that you are showing:

```
Private Sub SourceBox_Change()
    'subroutine to fire on combobox change event
    'print the value (hidden) and the text (shown) to debugger for fun and profit
    Debug.Print SourceBox.Value, SourceBox.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, looks good. Going to try that tomorrow. Do you have any good resources to learn about these kinds of manipulations?

Comment: Nothing off the top of my head, but I've always found MSDN to be pretty useful. It usually gives a good explanation of all the object's methods and parameters and relationships and all that.

Comment: I actually have the text that needs to be shown in column 1 and the value in column 2. So I tried SourceBox.ColumnWidths = "1;0", but this doesn't work since it's then showing the text twice in the Debug.Print. Is there some way to assign or tell the combobox which column to use for what?

Answer (score 0):

The most succinct way to get the second column would be something like

```
SourceBox.List = Range("SourceTable[Column2]").Value
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean by setting the name and storing the value. You can use dictionaries and you can use the built-in names collection for such things, though you would need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.

```
Sub passValueToComboBox1()
   Dim ie  As Object
   Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   ie.Visible = True
   ie.navigate "http://your_URL_here.php"
   While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

   Set oHTML_Element = ie.document.getElementsByName("selectedReportClass")(0)
   If Not oHTML_Element Is Nothing Then oHTML_Element.Value = "FUBU7"

   For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
      If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
   Next
End Sub
```

The easiest thing to do is hit F12 on your keyboard so you can see the HTML behind the page. Identify the ComboBox by name (it will be highlighted when you pass your mouse over the HTML code) or ID (0, 1, 2, etc.). Then, simply pass the value straight to the ComboBox.

Give it a try and see how it goes.

Finally, if F12 doesn't do anything, download and install the IE toolbar.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=32987